# How to trace interrupts?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, trace

I'm Curios to know if interrupt 10 when ah=10 (which print a char) will end up with    out instruction , Isn't This the core of output functionality?

I've tried debug.com in windows but it seems the disassembled code is wrong , also it never ends when I trace it (it reaches zeroes where no code actually there ).

How to trace interrupts ?

Comment: Interrupt handlers in Windows run in kernel mode, which you can't step into with a standard debugger.  You will need a kernel debugger such as found in the Windows Driver Kit.

Comment: No, video memory was memory-mapped.  Simply writing to a specific address would make a character appear on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, If I use MS_DOS can I just read the address 0000:0040 for the jump of int 10 ? (not in windows)

Comment: If you run Dosbox, you can get a complete execution trace of your program by using the built-in debugger, interrupts and system calls and all.

Comment: Thank you very much , I have virtual win98 on vmware , and I run it on ms-dos mode , and I was able to trace until reaching the "out" instructions level :)